# Rails 6 stylesheets and sass aren't loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I've got a new spree rails 6 application and I can't get any of the sass files to compile.  Here's my `assets/stylesheets` file:

```
stylesheets

  app
     _file.scss
     _another_file.scss

  mixins
     _mix-media-queries.scss
     _mix-general.scss

  modules
     _modules_file.scss

  application.css

  style.scss
```

`application.css`:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require ./style
```

`style.scss`:

```
@import "mixins/_mix-media-queries";
etc...
```

But when I load the page it give me this error:
`Error: Undefined variable: "$color-dark-red".` Which is an var in the mixins file.

`_head.html.erb`:

```
<title><%= title %></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<%== meta_image_data_tag %>
<%== meta_data_tags %>
<%= canonical_tag(current_store.url) %>
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'spree/frontend/all', media: 'screen', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= render 'spree/shared/paths' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'spree/frontend/all', defer: true, 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= yield :head %>
```

This is so frustrating as I cannot get the stupid styles to load!  I'm new to rails 6, is this a new rails 6 thing with the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Sprockets directives do not work well at all with SASS.

When you require SASS files with sprockets it will send the files through the SASS compiler one by one and then concatenate the results together. Of course this blows up as soon as one of your SASS files references a variable, include or function that is declared in any other file.

You need to change the extension of your `application.css` to `.scss` and only use SASS `@import` directives that tells the SASS compiler to pull in the other file.

#### is this a new rails 6 thing with the asset pipeline?

No. This applies to previous versions of Rails and both SASSC and the old Ruby Sass Compiler.

See:

- https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note